# Вывод всех статей сайтах из папок

Tags: php

Я изучаю php и решил написать программу для вывода всех статей сайта, которые находятся в папках, но у меня не получилось... помогите или скажите, что не так.

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $statji = "statji/$i";
    if (!file_exists($statji))
        break;
    $dir = opendir($statji);
    $raz = array(".html", ".htm", ".shtml", ".php");
    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        if(($file != ".") && ($file != "..") {
            if (in_array(strrchr($file, "."), $raz)) {
                $meta = get_meta_tags("$statji/$file");
                echo "<tr><td><a href='$statji/$file' target='_blank'>$meta[nazvanie]</a></td><td>$meta[avtor]</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}
$ind = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");
?>
```

Comment: а почемубы не хранить статьи в БД?

Comment: Я еще не умею.

Comment: Напишите конкретнее, что именно не получилось, т.е. смотрел в таких-то папках файлы (какие там лежат) , рассчитывал получить такой-то результат, а увидел...

Может быть просто вместо **break** Вам надо **continue** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема в синтаксисе... Допустим:

```
$statji="statji/$i"; => $statji="statji/".$i;
$meta=get_meta_tags("$statji/$file"); => $meta=get_meta_tags($statji."/".$file);
echo "...target='_blank'>$meta[nazvanie]</a>..<td>$meta[avtor]</td>..";     
=>    
echo "...target='_blank'>".$meta[nazvanie]."</a>..<td>".$meta[avtor]."</td>..";
```

и тд. Читайте, что вам выдает браузер (ошибки) и по ним отлаживайте работу скрипта.

Answer (score 1):

У вас вроде одна ошибка. Не хватает закрывающей скобки в условной конструкции `if (($file != "..") && ...) { //code }`. Вот работающий код, единственно вам прийдется или директорию переименовать или в коде поправить под свой стандарт.

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $articles = 'articles/'.$i;

    if (!file_exists($articles)) {
        break;
    }

    $dir = opendir($articles);
    $ext = array(".html", ".htm");

    while (($file = readdir($dir)) != false) {
        if ($file == "." || $file == "..") {
            continue;
        }

        if (in_array(strrchr($file, "."), $ext)) {
            $meta = get_meta_tags($articles ."/". $file);

            //Здесь выводите данные, которые хотели, надеюсь содержание файлов
            //у правильное, чтобы что-то выводилось.
        }
    }

    closedir($dir);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

в начале скрипта. И смотрите ошибки